symfony / validator 6.3 and swagger , type array
First experience with symphony, there is custom class FavoriteItemDto
with construct
public function __construct(
        #[Groups(["delete"])]
        #[Assert\NotBlank(groups: ['create', 'delete'])]
        public readonly ?int $itemId = null,

        #[Groups(["delete"])]
        #[Assert\NotBlank(groups: ['create', 'delete'])]
        #[Assert\Choice(callback: [Subsystem::class, 'values'], groups: ['create'])]
        public readonly ?string $subsystem = null,

        #[Assert\Type(type: 'integer', groups: ['create'])]
        public readonly ?int $eventTypeId = null,

        #[AssertType(type: 'array', groups: ['create'],)]
        public readonly ?array $itemIds = null,
    ) {
    }

Problem with variable itemIds, the code works but when trying to enter the swagger (/v1/account/doc) it gives an error
{"errors":[{"errorCode":500,"errorCause":"Property \u0022App\Model\FavoriteItemDto::itemIds\u0022 is an array, but its items type isn\u0027t specified. You can specify that by using the type string[] for instance or @OA\\Property(type=\u0022array\u0022, @OA\\Items(type=\u0022string\u0022))."}]}
if I understood correctly, then you need to explicitly specify the types of array elements, but I don't understand how, explain, please help ..
I read the documentation and didn't understand anything, I studied all similar questions and didn't understand either, please poke me in the face like a cat ...

It look like a serialization issue.
Try to define like this your array:
    #[ApiProperty(
        description: "List of item IDs",
        items: new \ApiPlatform\Metadata\PropertySchema(['type' => 'integer']),
        openapiContext: ['type' => 'array', 'items' => ['type' => 'integer']]
    )]
    #[Assert\Type(type: 'array', groups: ['create'])]
    public readonly ?array $itemIds = null,

Don't forget to call :
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiProperty;


I did as you advised, same error...
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "errorCode": 500,
      "errorCause": "Property \"App\\Model\\FavoriteItemDto::itemIds\" is an array, but its items type isn't specified. You can specify that by using the type `string[]` for instance or `@OA\\Property(type=\"array\", @OA\\Items(type=\"string\"))`."
    }
  ]
}


My reply should work if your array contain integer value.
That's the typing of the content of your array ? String ?

You can specify the type exactly as it says in the error message.
#[OA\Property(type: 'array', items: new OA\Items(type: 'integer'))]
#[Assert\Type(type: 'array', groups: ['create'])]
public readonly ?array $itemIds = null,

By the way you can validate items also. For example:
#[Assert\All([new Assert\Type('int'), new Assert\Positive])]

